# Combinatorial Nullstellenatz riddle

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I've been unable to solve the last problem here:
http://www.mit.edu/~evanchen/handouts/BMC_Combo_Null/BMC_Combo_Null.pdf

Let $n ≥ 2$ be even and let $v_1, v_2, . . . , v_k ∈ \{±1\}^n$
be vectors of length $n$ such that any $v ∈ \{±1\}^n$
is orthogonal to at least one of the $v_i$. Prove
that $k ≥ n$ and that this estimate is sharp.

Could anyone provide a hint/solution? I know how to find n vectors that satisfy the requirement, and I think I know the right polynomial to look at, but I can't seem to prove the appropriate coefficient is not $0$.

My progress:
The n vectors that work are:

{$\{1,1,1...1\}$ ,  ,$\{-1,1,1...1\}$...,$\{-1,-1..,-1\}$}.

Proof: if we assign names in order $v_i$, then $v*v_1 = -v*v_n$, also when we move from $v*v_i$ to $v*v_(i+1)$ we change the value by at most +-2, and all the products are even so by discrete intermediate value theorem it's 0 at some point.

The polynomial I think I'm supposed to look at is $(v*v_1)*(v*v_2)..(v*v_k)$

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to post what you have so far.

Comment: Okay, I was reluctant to fight with the Latex, but I'll try.